# function which given a point and a value of the area of a square as input parameter returns four squares

Tags: c

in this code i don't understand why teacher used sometimes +value, - value;

```
/******************************************/
// function void returnSquares(POINT point, int value)
void returnSquares(POINT point, int value) {
    SQUARE tabSquares[4];       // table of squares that we are creating
    int i;

    // getting points of 4 squares
    // for first square input point is point C
    tabSquares[0].pointA.dimX = point.dimX - value;
    tabSquares[0].pointA.dimY = point.dimY + value;
    tabSquares[0].pointB.dimX = point.dimX;
    tabSquares[0].pointB.dimY = point.dimY + value;
    tabSquares[0].pointC.dimX = point.dimX;
    tabSquares[0].pointC.dimY = point.dimY;
    tabSquares[0].pointD.dimX = point.dimX - value;
    tabSquares[0].pointD.dimY = point.dimY; 

    // for 2nd square input point is point D
    tabSquares[1].pointA.dimX = point.dimX;
    tabSquares[1].pointA.dimY = point.dimY + value;
    tabSquares[1].pointB.dimX = point.dimX + value;
    tabSquares[1].pointB.dimY = point.dimY + value;
    tabSquares[1].pointC.dimX = point.dimX + value;
    tabSquares[1].pointC.dimY = point.dimY;
    tabSquares[1].pointD.dimX = point.dimX;
    tabSquares[1].pointD.dimY = point.dimY; 

    // for 3rd square input point is point A
    tabSquares[2].pointA.dimX = point.dimX;
    tabSquares[2].pointA.dimY = point.dimY;
    tabSquares[2].pointB.dimX = point.dimX + value;
    tabSquares[2].pointB.dimY = point.dimY;
    tabSquares[2].pointC.dimX = point.dimX + value;
    tabSquares[2].pointC.dimY = point.dimY - value;
    tabSquares[2].pointD.dimX = point.dimX;
    tabSquares[2].pointD.dimY = point.dimY - value;

    // for 4th square input point is point B
    tabSquares[3].pointA.dimX = point.dimX - value;
    tabSquares[3].pointA.dimY = point.dimY;
    tabSquares[3].pointB.dimX = point.dimX;
    tabSquares[3].pointB.dimY = point.dimY;
    tabSquares[3].pointC.dimX = point.dimX;
    tabSquares[3].pointC.dimY = point.dimY - value;
    tabSquares[3].pointD.dimX = point.dimX - value;
    tabSquares[3].pointD.dimY = point.dimY - value;


    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        printf("Square number %d\n",i); // now we print parameters of each point in current Square
        printf("point A x= %0.2f y= %0.2f\n",tabSquares[i].pointA.dimX,tabSquares[i].pointA.dimY); 
        printf("point B x= %0.2f y= %0.2f\n",tabSquares[i].pointB.dimX,tabSquares[i].pointB.dimY);
        printf("point C x= %0.2f y= %0.2f\n",tabSquares[i].pointC.dimX,tabSquares[i].pointC.dimY);
        printf("point D x= %0.2f y= %0.2f\n",tabSquares[i].pointD.dimX,tabSquares[i].pointD.dimY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the image:

```
          C
D *-------*
  |       |
  |Square |
  |       |
  *-------* B
  A
```

The points A,B,C and D are marked as per their order assumed in your `SQUARE` data type.

Given a point X and the length of the square, the function generates four squares of that length. The order of these squares (as indicated by their index in the `tabSquares` array) is as follows:

```
*-------*------*
|       |      |
| Sq-3  | Sq-2 |
|       |      |
*-------X------*
|       |      |
| Sq-0  | Sq-1 |
|       |      |
*-------*------*
```

Thus, `tabSquares[0]` is the square marked `Sq-0` and its `pointA` is the bottom left corner. The x coordinate of that point is `value` units less than the x coordinate of the given point and y coordinate is `value` units more than y coordinate of the given point. (x increases from left to right and y increases from top to bottom - origin is the top left corner of the drawing area)

Hence:

```
tabSquares[0].pointA.dimX = point.dimX - value;
tabSquares[0].pointA.dimY = point.dimY + value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that code is designed to create a set of four square each having sides of length 'value that are connected together into a grid that is centred around the point 'point'.

The reason why he is using `+ value` and `- value` is because he is calculating the points that make up these other squares.

if the point (3,5) was passed in and the value was set as '2' then this code will create a square starting bottom left at (1,3) going to the top right at (5,7).

You should work through this on grid paper drawing the points as this is storing them in the array.

***simple short answer***

He is adding and subtracting `value`